# How old do you need to be to buy bitcoins in a atm?

Tags: legal

I've read all the others Q&A and I haven't found the answer to my question or I haven't noticed. I live in Spain and is there an age restriction to use an btc atm (I'm 16)?

Answer (score -1):

I know for age limits when buying alcohol, cigarets.....but for using ATM (normal usage or buying BTC)? Never heard for this....maybe you should first learn, how ic/is not BTC regulated in Spain (is it recognized as a curency, comodity ext...) and start from there?